# Audio capture in Android

Tags: android, audio-capture

What is the best way to capture audio? I have been reading Phonegap might not be reliable. Can  you guys share your thoughts on this.

thanks,
JD

Answer (score 1):

I haven't had a try yet, but here is a useful example for [**AudioRecord**](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Media/UsingAudioRecord.htm). I hope this will be useful for you to get further.